# How to get a MouseListener to stop being in control

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener

I am writing a trivia/quiz program in which the user answers questions and his/her answers are judged as correct or incorrect based on the screen coordinates they have clicked. For a clean design, I wish to load the questions using an external function, then attach a MouseListener to the screen object afterward.

My code currently resembles that given below.

```
void main() {
    screen = new QuizScreen();
    //load data for question
    screen.awaitAnswer();
}

public class QuizScreen implements MouseListener{
    //...variables...
    //...blank methods for MousePressed, MouseReleased, etc...
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
        //check if answer is right
    }

    public void awaitAnswer(){
        QuizScreen.addMouseListener(this);
    }
}
```

This code works fine for loading, allowing play of, and checking the answer to a single question. However, after the first question has been loaded, I want to be able to repeat the process -- to load ANOTHER (and possibly many more) questions -- by adding a loop to the "main" function. This is currently not possible, since I don't know how to get the MouseListener to stop listening to the user's clicks and return from awaitAnswer() to main().

How do I stop getting the MouseListener to listen to the user? How would I get out of an event-driven section of my code and back to an automatically executing section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the awaitAnswer method.

Create a (default) constructor for QuizScreen with statement `addMouseListener(this);`.

From your mouseClicked function, just execute a callback to your main program to create and destroy the QuizScreen